# Problem with JUNIT,Spring Test - Wanted but not invoked

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, junit

i keep getting this error message that it dosent make sense to me i need some help to understand whats going on i ve just started my journey in testing and i started by trying to test some of my implemented methods in my application i decided to start with this method below :

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class LoginService {

    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    JwtService jwtService;
    @Autowired
    LoginService(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JwtService jwtService){
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    public void logInUser(String username, String password, HttpServletResponse response){
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password);
        try{
            Authentication authUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            String accessToken = jwtService.createAccessJwtToken(username);
            String refreshToken = jwtService.createRefreshJwtToken(username);
            Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>();
            tokens.put("accessToken",accessToken);
            tokens.put("refreshToken",refreshToken);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(),tokens);
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new BadCredentialsException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

i tried to test but i had one problem that i dont understand what should i do i tried everything but it seems i have done something wrong here is the testing code and below is the problem :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class LoginServiceTest {

    @Mock
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Mock
    JwtService jwtService;
    @Mock
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;
    @Mock
    PrintWriter printWriter;
    @Mock
    Authentication authUser;
    @Mock
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    LoginService loginService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        this.loginService = new LoginService(authenticationManager,jwtService);
    }

    @Test
    void logInUser() throws Exception{
        String email = "test@test.com";
        String password = "test1234";
        Map<String,String> expectedTokens = new HashMap<>();
        String expectedCreatedAccessToken = "accessToken";
        String expectedCreatedRefreshToken = "refreshToken";
        expectedTokens.put("accessToken",expectedCreatedAccessToken);
        expectedTokens.put("refreshToken",expectedCreatedRefreshToken);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email,password);

        when(authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken)).thenReturn(authUser);
        when(jwtService.createAccessJwtToken(email)).thenReturn(expectedTokens.get("accessToken"));
        when(jwtService.createRefreshJwtToken(email)).thenReturn(expectedTokens.get("refreshToken"));
        when(httpServletResponse.getWriter()).thenReturn(printWriter);
        doNothing().when(objectMapper).writeValue(printWriter, expectedTokens);

        this.loginService.logInUser(email,password,httpServletResponse);

        verify(authenticationManager).authenticate(authToken);
        verify(httpServletResponse).getWriter();
        verify(jwtService).createAccessJwtToken(email);
        verify(jwtService).createRefreshJwtToken(email);
        verify(objectMapper).writeValue(printWriter,expectedTokens);
    }
}
```

the error:

> Wanted but not invoked: objectMapper.writeValue(
> printWriter,
> {"accessToken" = "accessToken", "refreshToken" = "refreshToken"} );`
>
> -> at com.project.requests.login.service.LoginServiceTest.logInUser(LoginServiceTest.java:67)
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

i tried almost everything playing around with the       `doNothing().when(objectMapper).writeValue(printWriter, expectedTokens);`
by removing it or adding some different arguments or using argument dependencies of mockito but nothing seems to solve my error

Comment: You can not mock the ObjectMapper, as it will  be created inside of the method. You have to refactor your code

Comment: i had misunderstood the use of mocking you was right thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use mocked objects, your service code must use dependency injection instead of creating the ObjectMapper itself using a constructor.

So, in order to make your code work you would need to inject ObjectMapper like that:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class LoginService {

    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    JwtService jwtService;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Autowired
    LoginService(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JwtService jwtService, ObjectMapper objectMapper){
    this.jwtService = jwtService;
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
    ...
}
```

Depending on your configuration, you may already have a ObjectMapper bean defined.
If not, you would need to define a configuration class which would register an ObjectMapper bean like that:

```
@Configuration
public class MapperConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
   }
}
```

Then, you will be able to inject a mocked ObjectMapper in your tests like that:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class LoginServiceTest {

    @Mock
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Mock
    JwtService jwtService;
    @Mock
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;
    @Mock
    PrintWriter printWriter;
    @Mock
    Authentication authUser;
    @Mock
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    LoginService loginService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        this.loginService = new LoginService(authenticationManager,jwtService, objectMapper);
    }
    // @Test ...
}
```

And then your mocked ObjectMapper will be properly injected and called as you expect.

On the side note, you use `@InjectMocks` annotation to create a service with mocked dependencies instead of creating it manually in the `@BeforeEach` method.